# How can I move a responsive hamburger menu to the right side of screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap and using it for a responsive navbar and it works fine except I want the collapsable hamburger menu to be on the right of the screen with the site name on the left, it is currently opposite.

I've tried mr-auto, ml-auto, pull-left, pull-right, and floats but nothing seems to be working.

```
   <button class='navbar-toggler' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#collapse-target'>
     <span><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
   </button>
   <div class='logo'>
     <h1>TC Barringer</h1>
     <h1>Photography</h1>
   </div>
   <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='collapse-target'>
     <ul class='navbar-nav ml-auto'>
       <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='index.html'>PORTFOLIO</a></li>
       <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='timandcourtney.html'>TIM & COURTNEY</a></li>
       <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='contact.html'>CONTACT US</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </nav>
```

Some of the Bootstrap classes like ml-auto will shift the button slightly but nothing I've tried will flip the site title and the button entirely. Any ideas?